# $x_0 ^2+x_0+1$ root of some polynomial in $\mathbb Z [X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I saw this problem somewhere and I am trying to solve this:

> If $x_0$ is a root of $X^3-X^2-15$ then $x_0 ^2+x_0+1$ is a root of some polynomial in $\mathbb Z [X]$.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Does "solve it" mean proving that such a polynomial exists, or does it mean to explicitly construct such a (minimal?) polynomial?

Comment: I expected it to solve using analysis, Is there any way to solve this using analysis?

Answer (score 1):

We have that $x_0$ is an algebraic number. As far as I remember, a sum and a product of algebaic numbers is again an algebraic number (see, for instance, "Algebra" by Serge Lang). Therefore $x_0^2+x_0+1$ should be an algebraic number too.

Comment: You're right, Alex: I thought it was written there somewhere that the integer polynomial had to be monic. Of course, +1